# How do I remove the "extended attributes" on a file in Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, attributes

I have an [AppleScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AppleScript) script that runs a stress test. Part of the test is to open, save, and close certain files. Somehow, the files have picked up some "extended attributes" that prohibit the files from being saved. That causes the stress test to fail.

How do I remove the extended attributes?

Comment: Extended attributes can't prevent a file from being saved. Are you sure it's not a permissions problem, or an ACL?

Comment: Did you just upgrade to 10.7.3? It seems there is a bug where many GUI apps (including TextEdit, but also other apps - including one I wrote myself which doesn't do anything strange) will now set the quarantine bit on files. As @Bavarious said, you can remove it using @xattr@. Look into TextWrangler, which is free, and I think has good AppleScript support. I'm told it doesn't set the quarantine bit.

Comment: In short: you don't need to remove these attributes unless you encounter some serious problem(s).

Answer (score 473):

Use the `xattr` command. You can inspect the extended attributes:

```
$ xattr s.7z
com.apple.metadata:kMDItemWhereFroms
com.apple.quarantine
```

and use the `-d` option to delete one extended attribute:

```
$ xattr -d com.apple.quarantine s.7z
$ xattr s.7z
com.apple.metadata:kMDItemWhereFroms
```

you can also use the `-c` option to remove all extended attributes:

```
$ xattr -c s.7z
$ xattr s.7z
```

`xattr -h` will show you the command line options, and [xattr has a man page](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/xattr.1.html).

Comment: Apple has a man page for it available online: http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/xattr.1.html

Comment: It appears that the -c option was removed in Mountain Lion (10.8). xattr -h no longer lists -c and produces "-c not recognized" when used. Very painful now to remove extended attributes one by one.

Comment: `-c` is not working for me (OS X 10.6.8). `-d` also didn't have any effect though it didn't complain. I had to explicitly name each extended attribute like so: `xattr -rd <attrname> <folder/file>` (deletes recursively). To find out the attributes present (likely the same attributes in the entire directory tree) use `xattr <dir/file>` as in the answer above.

Comment: @mindtheif no one mentioned here that this requires the xCode command line tools. On 10.6.8 it's called something different. [Here's a link](https://github.com/kennethreitz/osx-gcc-installer/) to a pre-built installer on GitHub so you don't have to install all of xCode to see if this is your problem.

Comment: With Xcode installed on my 10.8.5 system, `xattr -c` works fine for me (and successfully stripped all metadata).

Comment: I found I had to escalate privileges (sudo) to remove the 'com.apple.quarantine' attribute.

Comment: ***`-c`*** fails on OS X 10.5: ***`option -c not recognized`***. We use one for testing on Apple's PowerPC. It looks like the downlevel version of OS X supports ***`-l`***,  ***`-p`***,  ***`-w`*** and  ***`-d`***.

Comment: Note that if `xattr -c` fails with `Operation not permitted`, you may need to unlock the file using `sudo chflags nouchg {file_to_modify}`

Comment: @mindthief, I explain why you get the error in my answer below. https://stackoverflow.com/a/58616002/1896134

Comment: NO LONGER WORKS. xattr -c does not clear attributes. chflags nouchg does not change that. Using sudo does not change it. Installing Xcode command line tools does not fix it. The attribute clearing is either broken (modern apple software being what it is) or has changed. NO LONGER WORKS.

Answer (score 123):

### Removing a Single Attribute on a Single File

See Bavarious's answer.

---

### To Remove All Extended Attributes On a Single File

Use `xattr` with the `-c` flag to "clear" the attributes:

```
xattr -c yourfile.txt
```

---

### To Remove All Extended Attributes On Many Files

To recursively remove extended attributes on all files in a directory, combine the `-c` "clear" flag with the `-r` recursive flag:

```
xattr -rc /path/to/directory
```

---

#### A Tip for Mac OS X Users

Have a long path with spaces or special characters?

Open `Terminal.app` and start typing `xattr -rc`, include a trailing space, and then then drag the file or folder to the `Terminal.app` window and it will automatically add the full path with proper escaping.

Comment: ***`-c`*** fails on OS X 10.5: ***`option -c not recognized`***. We use one for testing on Apple's PowerPC. It looks like the downlevel version of OS X supports ***`-l`***,  ***`-p`***,  ***`-w`*** and  ***`-d`***.

Comment: @cwd: the Finder drag-n-drop into terminal does not work with some 'special' Finder files such as `. textClipping` as described in https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/301871/how-to-convert-finders-textclipping-files-to-plain-text/301873

Comment: @jww I explain why you get the error in my answer below. https://stackoverflow.com/a/58616002/1896134

Answer (score 28):

Try using:

```
xattr -rd com.apple.quarantine directoryname
```

This takes care of recursively removing the pesky attribute everywhere.

Answer (score 22):

---

## Answer (Individual Files)

---

#### 1. Showcase keys to use in selection.

```sh
xattr ~/Desktop/screenshot\ 2019-10-23\ at\ 010212.png
    # com.apple.FinderInfo
    # com.apple.lastuseddate#PS
    # com.apple.metadata:kMDItemIsScreenCapture
    # com.apple.metadata:kMDItemScreenCaptureGlobalRect
    # com.apple.metadata:kMDItemScreenCaptureType
```

#### 2. Pick a Key to delete.

```sh
xattr -d com.apple.lastuseddate#PS ~/Desktop/screenshot\ 2019-10-23\ at\ 010212.png
xattr -d kMDItemIsScreenCapture ~/Desktop/screenshot\ 2019-10-23\ at\ 010212.png
```

#### 3. Showcase keys again to see they have been removed.

```sh
xattr -l ~/Desktop/screenshot\ 2019-10-23\ at\ 010212.png
    # com.apple.FinderInfo
    # com.apple.metadata:kMDItemScreenCaptureGlobalRect
    # com.apple.metadata:kMDItemScreenCaptureType
```

#### 4. Lastly, REMOVE ALL keys for a particular file

```sh
xattr -c ~/Desktop/screenshot\ 2019-10-23\ at\ 010212.png
```

---

## Answer (All Files In A Directory)

---

#### 1. Showcase keys to use in selection.

```sh
xattr -r ~/Desktop
```

#### 2. Remove a Specific Key for EVERY FILE in a directory

```sh
xattr -rd com.apple.FinderInfo ~/Desktop
```

#### 3. Remove ALL keys on EVERY FILE in a directory

```sh
xattr -rc ~/Desktop
```

> **WARN: Once you delete these you DON'T get them back!**
>   ***FAULT ERROR: There is NO UNDO.***

---

## Errors

---

I wanted to address the error's people are getting.
**Because the errors drove me nuts too...**
On a mac if you install `xattr` in python, then your environment may have an issue.

> There are two different paths on my mac for `xattr`

```sh
type -a xattr

    # xattr is /usr/local/bin/xattr    # PYTHON Installed Version
    # xattr is /usr/bin/xattr          # Mac OSX Installed Version
```

So in one of the example's where `-c` will not work in xargs is because in bash you default to the non-python version.

#### Works with `-c`

```sh
/usr/bin/xattr -c
```

#### Does NOT Work with `-c`

```sh
/usr/local/bin/xattr -c
    # option -c not recognized
```

My Shell/Terminal defaults to  /usr/local/bin/xattr because my `$PATH`
`/usr/local/bin:` is before `/usr/bin:` which I believe is the default.

I can prove this because, if you try to uninstall the python `xattr` you will see:

```sh
pip3 uninstall xattr
Uninstalling xattr-0.9.6:
  Would remove:
    /usr/local/bin/xattr
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/xattr-0.9.6.dist-info/*
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/xattr/*
Proceed (y/n)?
```

---

## Workarounds

---

To Fix `option -c not recognized` Errors.

1. Uninstall any Python `xattr` you may have: `pip3 uninstall xattr`
2. Close all `Terminal` windows & quit `Terminal`
3. Reopen a new `Terminal` window.
4. ReRun `xattr` command and it should now work.

OR

> If you want to keep the Python `xattr` then use

```sh
/usr/bin/xattr
```

for any `Shell` commands in `Terminal`

---

#### Example:

---

Python's version of `xattr` doesn't handle images at all:

```sh
Good-Mac:~ JayRizzo$ xattr ~/Desktop/screenshot\ 2019-10-23\ at\ 010212.png
    # com.apple.FinderInfo
    # Traceback (most recent call last):
    #   File "/usr/local/bin/xattr", line 8, in <module>
    #     sys.exit(main())
    #   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/xattr/tool.py", line 196, in main
    #     attr_value = attr_value.decode('utf-8')
    # UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xb0 in position 2: invalid start byte

Good-Mac:~ JayRizzo$ /usr/bin/xattr ~/Desktop/screenshot\ 2019-10-23\ at\ 010212.png
    # com.apple.FinderInfo
    # com.apple.lastuseddate#PS
    # com.apple.metadata:kMDItemIsScreenCapture
    # com.apple.metadata:kMDItemScreenCaptureGlobalRect
    # com.apple.metadata:kMDItemScreenCaptureType
```

### Man Pages

[MAN PAGE for OSX xattr](https://ss64.com/osx/xattr.html)

[MAN PAGE for Python xattr VERSION 0.6.4](http://www.cc.kyoto-su.ac.jp/~atsushi/Programs/VisualWorks/CSV2HTML/CSV2HTML_PyDoc/xattr.html#xattr)

> NOTE: I **could not** find the python help page for current VERSION 0.9.6

Thanks for Reading!

Answer (score 8):

Another recursive approach:

```
# change directory to target folder:
cd /Volumes/path/to/folder

# find all things of type "f" (file), 
# then pipe "|" each result as an argument (xargs -0) 
# to the "xattr -c" command:
find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 xattr -c

# Sometimes you may have to use a star * instead of the dot.
# The dot just means "here" (whereever your cd'd to
find * -type f -print0 | xargs -0 xattr -c
```

Comment: ***`-c`*** fails on OS X 10.5: ***`option -c not recognized`***. We use one for testing on Apple's PowerPC. It looks like the downlevel version of OS X supports ***`-l`***,  ***`-p`***,  ***`-w`*** and  ***`-d`***.

Comment: @jww I explain why you get the error in my answer below. https://stackoverflow.com/a/58616002/1896134