# What causes "Unable to access jarfile" error?

Tags: java, jar, executable-jar

I want to execute my program without using an IDE. 
I've created a jar file and an exectuable jar file. When 
I double click the exe jar file, nothing happens, and when I try to use the command in cmd it gives me this:

```
Error: Unable to access jarfile <path>
```

I use the command: `java -jar Calculator.jar`

How I created the jar:

1. Right click on project folder (Calculator)
2. Select
3. Click on Java Folder and select "Exectuable Jar File", then select next
4. Launch Configuration: Main - Calculator
5. Create Export Destination
6. Hit "Finish" and profit! Well, not really.

Comment: Sounds like the Jar is corrupt in some way, possibly missing the Manifest entry.

Comment: You should show how you created the JARs, what's in them and how you try to run the program. The Java code is irrelevant here.

Comment: Have you tried relaunching elcipse and recompiling? Sometimes Eclipse has does some strange things that can be avoided by relaunching.

Comment: I find the code difficult to read and think about. And what's the point of having everything in a static main function and having a single instance method to clear the console?

Comment: MadProgrammer: How can I fix this?
Jochen: Will Do. I'll edit it now.
MattS: Yes i've tried that multiple times
Dave: Because I've only scratched the surface of Java and i dont really know what "beautiful" code looks like :)

Comment: At the command line are you in the same folder as the jar file when you try to run java -jar Calculator.jar?

Comment: Yes I have placed the .jar file on my desktop, this is the line exactly - C:\Users\jsmit1061\Desktop

Comment: I have no answers to my problem, i answered it myself, and there is no way to show my appreciation in the comments, other than thanking them via reply. Please Reread your comment.

Comment: This error message is displayed also when trying to launch a folder and not a `.jar` file.

Comment: I was able to solve it by passing absolute path for the jar file after the command "java -jar /home/aboslute_path_to_the_jar_file.jar". Hope it helps.

Comment: happened to me when i had the jar open in one terminal window, would't allow write to directory, then opened up another terminal and tried to run the same jar

Comment: for me it was a silly typo.. i was giving  lambok.jar instead of lombok.jar

Comment: Sometimes you just have a wrong filename of the jar. Double check the jar name.

Answer (score 90, accepted):

**Fixed**

I just placed it in a different folder and it worked.

Comment: Can someone explain why this happened?

Comment: Sounds like it could have been a file permissions issue, however total guess.

Comment: sometimes it happens in mac. if I copy ms bat file to sh and modify it to make it work in mac, i get the same error. It is better to create new sh file in mac to get rid of the problem. The reason should be hidden chars in ms file.

Comment: I had a similar issue on WIndows, using cygwin. So cygwin uses different paths than windows `/cygdrive/c/` vs `C:\ ` I fixed this by using `realpath --relative-to=$(pwd) path/to/jarfile` So it will always enforce a relative path iso using `/cygdrive/c/.../path/to/jarfile`

Comment: I had the same problem, with my jar too, i accidentally mistyped the path of the jar

Comment: Try original path of the jar file.

Comment: It's because when you changed the location, you had to name the specific path to jar

Comment: @Rik Your comment is helpful although it won't work in dos paths and java file in cygwin path. The solution here will be `java -jar $(cygpath -a -d \`realpath --relative-to=$(pwd) $HOME/opt/javafile.jar\`)`

Comment: I've seen this happen with jar files inside `Documents` or `Desktop` folders on Mac and Windows. It allegedly has to do with some security mechanism aimed to prevent non-technical users from executing downloaded files. In our case the jar was executed by a Gradle build so this was at the bottom of a pretty long stack trace.

Answer (score 119):

I had encountered this issue when I had run my Jar file as

**`java -jar TestJar`**

instead of

**`java -jar TestJar.jar`**

Missing the extension **.jar** also causes this issue.

Comment: This is the correct answer. The .jar extension must be appended to the jar file name.

Comment: It's not always the correct answer, I'm appending it and it doesn't work.

Comment: In my case I thought it was a file while it was a folder on the console. The jar file was in a folder that has the same name.

Comment: This is always the incorrect Answer for this Question - the Question mentioned using the `.jar` extension; it wasn't missing.  Although this Answer may help in some similar situations, it wasn't the answer to this Question's particular situation.

Comment: in the original question person already put `java -jar Calculator.jar`, so what is the point of that "add extension" note?

Answer (score 48):

[Possibly Windows only]

Beware of spaces in the path, even when your jar is in the current working directory.  For example, for me this was failing:

```
java -jar myjar.jar
```

I was able to fix this by givng the full, quoted path to the jar:

```
java -jar "%~dp0\myjar.jar"
```

Credit goes to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17064031/14952%20%22this%20answer) for setting me on the right path....

Comment: Thanks for this. Need to give the full path in Linux as well, if trying to run it from a different directory.

Comment: This answer is partly a duplicate of an already given answer on this question. This is the earlier answer with the same method: full quoted path.
[Sep 6 '15](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32426647/6006571) by @benez

Answer (score 27):

I had this issue under CygWin in Windows. I have read elsewhere that Java does not understand the CygWin paths (`/cygdrive/c/some/dir` instead of `C:\some\dir`) - so I used a relative path instead: `../../some/dir/sbt-launch.jar`.

Comment: I was having this exact issue in CygWin! Thank you forever!

Comment: In cases where you need cygwin to use windows formatted paths instead of cygwin paths you can use the cygpath -w /path/here command to convert the path to the windows equivalent.

Comment: @JasonSlobotski thanks for the tip, I think your comment should be an answer on its own.

Answer (score 25):

I had the same issue when trying to launch the jar file. The path contained a space, so I had to place quotes around. Instead of:

```
java -jar C:\Path to File\myJar.jar
```

i had to write

```
java -jar "C:\Path to File\myJar.jar"
```

Comment: The quotations did the trick for me since I also had spaces inbetween. I then tried it without spaces in the path and without quotation marks and then it worked also

Comment: Anno 2019: This solution helped for me, with quotation marks! Without quotation marks and without spaces it doesn't work in my case.

Answer (score 17):

Just came across the same problem trying to make a bad USB...

I tried to run this command in admin cmd

```
java -jar c:\fw\ducky\duckencode.jar -I c:\fw\ducky\HelloWorld.txt  -o c:\fw\ducky\inject.bin
```

But got this error:

```
Error: unable to access jarfile c:\fw\ducky\duckencode.jar
```

**Solution**

**1st step**

Right click the jarfile in question. Click properties. 
Click the unblock tab in bottom right corner.
The file was blocked, because it was downloaded and not created on my PC.

**2nd step**

In the cmd I changed the directory to where the jar file is located.

```
cd C:\fw\ducky\
```

Then I typed `dir` and saw the file was named `duckencode.jar.jar`

So in cmd I changed the original command to reference the file with `.jar.jar`

```
java -jar c:\fw\ducky\duckencode.jar.jar -I c:\fw\ducky\HelloWorld.txt  -o c:\fw\ducky\inject.bin
```

That command executed without error messages and the inject.bin I was trying to create was now located in the directory.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, mine too was named as apktool.jar.jar

Comment: Thanks. The first step was what I needed. And second part was a typo while writing filename.

Answer (score 11):

None of the provided answers worked for me on macOS 11 Big Sur. The problem turned out to be that programs require special permission to access the Desktop, Documents, and Downloads folders, and Java breaks both the exception for directly opened files and the permission request popup.

Fixes:

- Move the .jar into a folder that isn’t (and isn’t under) Documents, Desktop, or Downloads.
- Manually grant the permission. Go to System Preferences → Security and Privacy → Privacy → Files and Folders → java, and check the appropriate folders.

Answer (score 8):

If you are using OSX, downloaded files are tagged with a security flag that prevents unsigned applications from running.

to check this you can view extended attributes on the file

```
$ ls -l@
-rw-r--r--@ 1 dave  staff  17663235 13 Oct 11:08 server-0.28.2-java8.jar
com.apple.metadata:kMDItemWhereFroms         619
com.apple.quarantine          68
```

You can then clear the attributes with

```
xattr -c file.jar
```

Comment: see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4833052/how-do-i-remove-the-extended-attributes-on-a-file-in-mac-os-x and https://superuser.com/questions/526920/how-to-remove-quarantine-from-file-permissions-in-os-x

Answer (score 8):

I had a similar problem and I even tried running my CMD with administrator rights, but it did not solve the problem.

The basic thing is to make sure to change the **Directory** in cmd to the **current directory** where your jar file is.

Do the following steps:

1. Copy jar file to Desktop.
2. Run CMD
3. Type command `cd desktop`
4. Then type `java -jar filename.jar`

This should work.

---

**Edit**: From JDK-11 onwards ( [JEP 330](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/330): Launch Single-File Source-Code Programs )

Since Java 11, java command line tool has been able to run a single-file source-code directly. e.g.

```
java filename.java
```

Answer (score 5):

It can also happen if you don't properly supply your list of parameters. Here's what I was doing:

```
java -jar test@gmail.com testing_subject file.txt test_send_emails.jar
```

Instead of the correct version:

```
java -jar test_send_emails.jar test@gmail.com testing_subject file.txt
```

Answer (score 5):

This worked for me.

```
cd /path/to/the/jar/

java -jar ./Calculator.jar
```

Answer (score 4):

For me it happens if you use native Polish chars in foldername that is in the PATH.
So maybe using untypical chars was the reason of the problem.

Answer (score 3):

sometime it happens when you try to (run or create) a .jar file under /libs folder by right click it in android studio. you can select the dropdown in top of android stuio and change it to **app**. This will work

[image]

Answer (score 2):

My particular issue was caused because I was working with directories that involved symbolic links (shortcuts). Consequently, trying `java -jar ../../myJar.jar` didn't work because I wasn't where I thought I was.

Disregarding relative file paths fixed it right up.

Answer (score 2):

In my case the suggested file name to be used was `jarFile*.jar` in the command line. The file in the folder was `jarFile-1.2.3.jar` . So I renamed the file to `jarFile`. Then I used `jarFile.jar` instead of `jarFile*.jar` and then the problem got resolved

Comment: after doing this, my unable to access jar file issue resolved.

Answer (score 2):

It can happen on a windows machine when you have spaces in the names of the folder. The solution would be to enter the path between " ". 
For example:

```
java -jar c:\my folder\x.jar    --> 
java -jar "c:\my folder\x.jar"
```

Comment: this does not answer the question, you should use comments to ask for more information.

Answer (score 2):

To avoid any permission issues, try to run it as administrator. This worked for me on Win10.

Comment: what about mac?

Answer (score 2):

I know this thread is years ago and issue was fixed too. But I hope this would helps someone else in future since I've encountered some similar issues while I tried to install Oracle WebLogic 12c and Oracle OFR in which its installer is in `.jar` format. For mine case, it was either didn't wrap the JDK directory in quotes or simply typo.

Run `Command Prompt` as administrator and execute the command in this format. Double check the sentence if there is typo.

> `"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.xxxxx\bin\java" -jar C:\Users\xxx\Downloads\xxx.jar`

If it shows something like `JRE 1.xxx is not a valid JDK Java Home`, make sure the System variables for `JAVA_HOME` in Environment Variables is pointing to the correct JDK directory. JDK 1.8 or above is recommended (2018).

A useful thread here, you may refer it: [Why its showing your JDK c:program files\java\jre7 is not a valid JDK while instaling weblogic server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37001407/why-its-showing-your-jdk-cprogram-files-java-jre7-is-not-a-valid-jdk-while-inst)

Answer (score 2):

For me it happen because i run it with default java version (7) and not with compiled java version (8) used to create this jar.

So i used:

```
%Java8_64%\bin\java -jar myjar.jar
```

Instead of java 7 version:

```
java -jar myjar.jar
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem where TextMate or something replaced the double quotes with the unicode double quotes.

Changing my `SELENIUM_SERVER_JAR` from the unicode double quotes to regular double quotes  and that solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

this is because you are looking for the file in the wrong path
1. look for the path of the folder where you placed the file
2. change the directory cd in cmd use the right path

Answer (score 1):

I use NetBeans and had the same issue. After I ran build and clean project my program was executable. The Java documentation says that the build/clean command is for rebuilding the project from scratch basically and removing any past compiles. I hope this helps. Also, I'd read the documentation. Oracle has NetBeans and Java learning trails. Very helpful. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you have specified the wrong version of your jar.

Answer (score 1):

I finally pasted my jar file into the same folder as my JDK so I didn't have to include the paths.  I also had to open the command prompt as an admin.

1. Right click Command Prompt and "Run as administrator"
2. Navigate to the directory where you saved your jdk to
3. In the command prompt type:  `java.exe -jar <jar file name>.jar`

Answer (score 1):

Keep the file in same directory where you are extracting it. That worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

If you are on WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux), and following a guide which say, says this:

```
java -Djava.library.path=./DynamoDBLocal_lib -jar DynamoDBLocal.jar -sharedDb
```

You actually need to specify the full path, even though you've provided it in the `java.library.path` part.

```
java -Djava.library.path=/mnt/c/dynamodb_local/DynamoDBLocal_lib -jar /mnt/c/dynamodb_local/DynamoDBLocal.jar -sharedDb
```

Comment: What is wsl?   about

Comment: @1.21gigawatts I've edited to explain

Answer (score 1):

This is permission issue, see if the directory is under your User.
That's why is working in another folder!

Answer (score 1):

**Rename the jar file and try**

Explanation :
yes, I know there are many answers still I want to add one point here which I faced.

I built the jar and I moved it into the server where I deploy (This is the normal process)
here the file name which I moved already existed in the server, here the file will override obviously right. In this case, I faced this issue.
maybe at the time of overriding there can be a permission copy issue.

Hope this will help someone.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to run it under administrator privoleges? 
meaning, running the command in "Run As" and then select administrator with proper admin credentials

worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I was trying this:

After giving the file read, write, execute priviledges:

`chmod 777 java-repl.jar`

`alias jr="java -jar $HOME/Dev/java-repl/java-repl.jar"`

Unable to access bla bla..., this was on Mac OS though

So I tried this:

`alias jr="cd $HOME/Dev/java-repl/ && java -jar java-repl.jar"`

Answer (score 0):

This did not work "Unable to access jarfile"

```
"C:\Program Files\java\jdk-13+33-jre\bin\javaw.exe" -jar "C:\Program Files\Maxim Integrated Products\1-Wire Drivers x64\ OneWireViewer.jar"
```

This does work

```
"C:\Program Files\java\jdk-13+33-jre\bin\javaw.exe" -jar "C:\Program Files\Maxim Integrated Products\1-Wire Drivers x64\OneWireViewer.jar"
```

The difference is the single space in front of OneWireViewer.jar not withstanding that it is surrounded with quotes and even has other spaces.

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem got resolved after accessing the folder in which the jar was placed
earlier I was giving command on D: drive, but when I navigated to the folder in which that jar was placed this problem got resolved

Answer (score 0):

If you're working with shared folders on a virtual machine (in my case virtualbox), it seems all my permission were missing to access the file. Additionally, it required elevated privileges to chmod the file.

```bash
sudo chmod +rwx filename.jar
```

After this you should be able to access the jarfile normally.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the / of the jar's path pointed to the root directory of the filesystem, not the root of the project.

The path was fixed by replacing / by ./ to get the current working directory instead of the root directory.

This is possible if you're running the command on another filesystem like with heroku: heroku local web for example.

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying the full path to the `.jar` file 0 That was a likely cause of the [Accepted Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11943948/what-causes-unable-to-access-jarfile-error?page=1&tab=trending#comment101068439_11963966).

So for example (if executing from the root of the project):
`java -jar target/Calculator.jar`

Comment: still doesn't work, it would fail as " Error: Unable to access jarfile /opt/ords/ords.war"

Answer (score 0):

Just need to provide exact location of the jar file in quotation ""

instead

```
java -jar -Dspring.profiles.active=local compass.jar
```

you have to provide (if it is inside target folder)

```
java -jar -Dspring.profiles.active=local "target/compass.jar"
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue. Moving jar to D drive solved the issue.
[image]

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35756350)

Answer (score -1):

first I created a variable `%JAVA_HOME% :`

When you downloaded the file, make sure to check `UNBLOCK TAB` in file properties as shown above in "maartencls" post .

```
c:\users\my user\downloads\location of the file\all> java -jar yourfilename.jar
```

hope this will resolve the issue :)

Answer (score -1):

You can specify the full path to your `java.exe` file, for example:

`"c:\Program Files\Java\jdk-9.0.4\bin\java.exe" -jar path_to_your_jar_file.jar`

it helped me.

Or check what `java.exe` file runs for default in your system, especially if you have many versions of JDK/JRE.

Answer (score -2):

In my issue to access directory from Command line (in windows) this error

> "unnable to access ..."

because wrong file extension

> file.jar.jar

! , so change it to correct one

> file.jar

:) good luck

Answer (score -2):

First run: `java -version`

and then run: `java -jar Calculator.jar`

This worked for me.

Comment: Not sure why the `java -version` is needed here? Also, running `java -jar Calculator.jar` is what the OP did and didn't work....