# Current working directory for SXPG_COMMAND_EXECUTE?

Tags: command-line, abap, sap-basis

Is there a way to specify the current working directory for the system command executed by the function module `SXPG_COMMAND_EXECUTE`?

I do not see any parameter which would allow me to do that either by defining the command in transaction `SM69` or on the list of `IMPORTING` parameters in `SE37`.

It looks like by default such commands are started in `DIR_HOME` which can be viewed by the transaction `AL11`. Do I have any control over that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a way of doing it via `SM69' unfortunately. I think the only solution is to create a script and call that.

I was going to suggest wrapping the statements in a `SM69` command defined as a call to `sh` with parameters of `-c 'cd <dir> && /path/to/command'` but unfortunately that doesn't work. According to note [401095](http://service.sap.com/sap/support/notes/401095) wildcards are not permitted. When I tested, `&&` was translated into a single `&`, causing the command to fail.

Answer (score 0):

Would be good if you access this information using FM `FILE_GET_NAME_USING_PATH` (export the script name for which you want to find the physical directory). 
The recieving path can be used in `SXPG_COMMAND_EXECUTE`.

Answer (score 0):

Because the external commands I called were actually `.bat` files I solved this by putting the following expression at the beginning of each and every one.

```
cd /d %~dp0
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17063947/get-current-batchfile-directory) Stackoverflow question helped a lot actually.