# How do you get the file path of a batch file without the file name?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am trying to get the file path of the batch script file that I made.
I want the script to take the current path of the batch file and remove the file name and stores it in a variable, so it looks like this:

`C:/path/to/batch/`

Not like this: `C:/path/to/batch/file.bat`

I don't want: `file.bat` in the file path.

Here is my batch file:

```
@echo off
echo grabbing file path...
set filePath=%0
pause %filePath%
```

Comment: Lookup the `%~dp` modifers in `call /?`.

Comment: @dxiv alrighty, thanks for your input.

Comment: I google searched your exact question and the first 4 links were links to StackOverFlow giving the same answer about using the modifiers dp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As given in the answer to this question: [Get current batchfile directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17063947/get-current-batchfile-directory) you can accomplish what your after with

```
%~dp0
```

so in your example code

```
@echo off
echo grabbing file path...
set "filePath=%~dp0"
echo %filePath%
pause
```

*Edit - fixed space and added quotes as suggested by commenter*