# Get the current path of the .bat file within the same .bat file

Tags: batch-file, windows-services

I am trying to create a windows service of some **.exe** file by using **.bat** file. As far as I know I need to use the path of the **.exe** file i want to run as service. But in generally the path of **.exe** file can be different, so I cannot use static path in the **.bat** file. I can solve the part of my problem by placing **.exe** and **.bat** files in the same direction, but I need to somehow get the direction of the **.bat** file  within itself and add the name of my **.exe** file. It is just an idea so is it possible to do it in **.bat** file ?

Thank you

P.S.

To run .exe as a windows service, I use .bat file with the following script

```
SC create MyService displayname= "MyService" binpath= "<path of exe>\NAME.exe" start= auto

SC failure MyService reset= 86400 actions= restart/1000/restart/1000/run/1000

sc failure MyService command= "\"<path of exe>\NAME.exe""
```

Comment: By starting an .exe that makes up a Windows Service, you're not starting it as a service (unless the executable, when invoked as an application, starts its associated service). Do you intend to invoke `net start $servicename`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get current batchfile directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17063947/get-current-batchfile-directory)

Comment: To run .exe as a windows service, I use .bat file with the following script





[ SC create MyService displayname= "MyService" binpath= "<path of exe>\NAME.exe" start= auto

SC failure MyService reset= 86400 actions= restart/1000/restart/1000/run/1000

sc failure MyService command= "\"<path of exe>\NAME.exe"" ]

Comment: That's creating a service, not running it. Anyway see duplicate.

Comment: Thanx for reply

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `%~dp0`

This example will set the path of the batch file you are running the code from.

```
set filepath=%~dp0
echo %filepath:~0,-1%
```