# NSSM will not pickup executable directory

Tags: windows, service, windows-server-2012-r2, nssm

I'm trying to use the Non-Sucking Service Manager (NSSM) to create a service. Unfortunately, for whatever reason, NSSM won't play ball.

I'm trying to install the service using the following command:

```
nssm install "My Service" "C:\Program Files\Vendor\bin\windows\service-start.bat"
```

The service is successfully created. However, when I go to Services and Right-Click on "My Service" and view the properties the "Path to executable" field is set to the path of NSSM itself. In this case, 'C:\Program Files\nssm-2.24\win64\nssm.exe'.

I've attempted to change this using the following command:

```
nssm set "My Service" AppDirectory "C:\Program Files\Vendor\bin\windows\service-start.bat"
```

This doesn't make any difference and the executable path remains the same.

I'm trying to do this on Windows Server 2012 R2.

Answer (score 3):

As CodeCaster mentioned, the 'Path to Executable' is correctly referring to nssm. Since nssm is a wrapper, you technically tell nssm to manage your service.

If you want to verify if your installed service *actually* refers to your service, you will need to check that in nssm instead. You can do so with below command:

```
nssm edit <servicename>
```

Here you can see what is configured for your service and you can do some extra configuration here as well. 
I hope that clarifies things a bit.

Answer (score 0):

NSSM is a wrapper which responds to SCM commands... which a batch file won't.

When registering the service, `...service-start.bat` is configured as a commandline arguments to the NSSM executable.

Comment: Hi, thanks for getting back to me but that doesn't really address the issue encountered. NSSM ignores the path to the executable I set irrespective of the file type. I've tried with .bat, .exe. and .cmd.

Comment: Then you're not asking the question you want answered. The _"path to the executable"_ is the path to the service executable. In this case, this is NSSM's path, which is correct.

Comment: You're [probably just looking for `%0`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17063947/get-current-batchfile-directory) to get the batch file's location.