# How to create bat file for python file and allow another person to open it from their computer?

Tags: python, batch-file

I'm trying to convert my python code into bat file.

I used the following guide: https://datatofish.com/batch-python-script/ but the problem it relies on pathes from my own computer, and when i sent it to someone else he wasn't able to run it.

this is what i put in my txt file:

```
"C:\Users\Adi Portal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe" "C:\Users\Adi Portal\PycharmProjects\War_Management_Project\CompanyCommander.py"
pause
```

I would like to know what should i change in the txt file so other people can run it in their computer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can count on them having installed Python globally (with admin privileges) and that the `.bat` file will be in the same directory as the `.py` file, you can use:

```
py.exe -3 "%~dp0\CompanyCommander.py"
```

`py.exe` is the [Windows launcher](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0397/) that is stored in a common location and can find installed copies of Python. `-3` tells it to run the latest installed version of Python 3 available. `%~dp0` is [the drive & path containing the batch script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17064031/364696), so if the Python file is in the same directory, it will be found.

Note that thanks to the Windows launcher, you may not need to use a `.bat` file at all. If Python was installed with admin privileges and associated with the `.py` extension, then all you need is a UNIX-style shebang line at the top:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
```

and to add a line at the very end of the script:

```
input("Press enter to exit...")
```

The Windows launcher recognizes shebang lines and handles them appropriately, and the `input` function will provide the same basic functionality as a batch script's `pause`.

Comment: Do you happen to know where needing the shebang line is documented?  I had thought on windows you didn't even need that much, that the extension was enough to run the script.

Comment: @AnonCoward: You want the shebang line to explicitly specify the Python version (and bonus, make portable scripts work on both Windows and UNIX-likes); the OP was explicitly launching using Python 3 in their original attempt, so a shebang makes it clear it's intended for Python 3, even if omitting the shebang line would launch the most recent version of Python anyway. It's not critical, but I prefer to include it for the portability reasons (and to be in the habit in case I'm working with Py2 scripts where the shebang *is* necessary on Windows).