# Is there a way to reference a WinSCP script's directory to download files there?

Tags: batch-file, sftp, winscp

I have a pretty standard WinSCP SFTP script that grabs a few files and saves them to a SharePoint library. The script gets called from VBA so I cannot leave `lcd` blank. The location of the library is slightly different for different users so I need a way to get the script's location.

The script is stored in a synced SharePoint folder: `%USERPROFILE%\User-Path\FTP\`

For other users that path might be `%USERPROFILE%\UserPath-FTP\FTP`.

```
@echo off

"C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\WinSCP.com" ^
 /command ^
    "open sftp://mysite.gov/ -hostkey=""ssh-rsa 4096 key#######=""" ^
    "cd /" ^
    "lcd ""%CD%""" ^
    "get File1.TXT" ^
    "get File2.csv" ^
    "get File3.csv" ^
    "exit"
timeout 10
exit
```

This code does not work when called from VBA, it fails to download the files to the `lcd`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand it correctly, you want WinSCP to download the files to the folder where the batch file is stored? (there's no *WinSCP script* involved)

See [Get current batchfile directory](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17063947/850848).

You can use it like this:

```
@echo off

cd /D %~dp0

"C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\WinSCP.com" ^
 /command ^
    "open sftp://example.com/ -hostkey=""ssh-rsa 4096 key#######=""" ^
    "cd /" ^
    "get File1.TXT" ^
    "get File2.csv" ^
    "get File3.csv" ^
    "exit"
```

(and drop the `lcd` line from WinSCP commandline)

Comment: cd /D %~dp0 worked, thank you.