# Unable to access .jar file

Tags: jar, javafx

[Error: Unable To Access Jar File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11943948/error-unable-to-access-jar-file)

this guy had the same problem, unfortunately i did not completely understood where did he move his .jar file. Mine is on desktop and i get unable to access on "cmd" aswell.

I created my .jar same way - exported from Eclipse, to desktop.

Answer (score 0):

I'm answering my own question, since i found a problem to my solution, got it by lucky and it may be help for others aswell, since the internet did not quite exactly knew what i was doing wrong.

So the idea where to move it is in your project's folder. Simple as that. After moving there, it worked like a charm :).