# How to redirect console to new window in Java

Tags: java, eclipse, console

I created a program that is console based, but the problem I have is when (Through eclipse) I turn it into a runnable .jar file and run it, nothing happens. I believe this is because it is printing to the console but the .jar has no idea how it's supposed to show that. So my question is is there a way to redirect the console to a new window? I have seen similar questions but none of the methods seem to work. I cannot use the console because I plan on giving this to extended family that has no idea how to use it from the command prompt, and are not computer savvy
Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5774970/run-jar-file-in-command-prompt run your jar from console

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you're using Windows, try running the jar from a console window thats already open:

`java -jar myJar.jar`

This will display the output in your existing console window.

You're not seeing anything when running the `jar` from the explorer because it finishes too fast and closes it's window upon completion before you can properly see it.

Comment: My problem with doing this is that I plan on giving this to my entire family, and that is not easy when my extended family is VERY extended.

Comment: To force the window to stay open instead, you could add `Thread.sleep(Long.MAX_VALUE);` to the end of your program.

Comment: Where do you mean by 'end'?  And when I try to rrun it from command prompt it just says 'Error: Unable to access jarfile ******.jar'

Comment: With _at the end_ I mean at the very bottom of your `main()` method. Also: [Unable to access Jar File](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11943948/error-unable-to-access-jar-file)

Comment: When I paste it in I get errors, I either have to put it in a try-catch statement or add something to my main method

Comment: As for the directory, if I have a space in one of the files do I replace it with an underscore?

Comment: No. Also, [spaces in filenames are a bad idea.](http://superuser.com/questions/29111/what-technical-reasons-exist-for-not-using-space-characters-in-file-names)

Comment: I have no choice =P It's the name of my PC