# "Error: Unable to access jarfile" command executed using Runtime exec

Tags: java, jar

I am developing a Java application where one of its task is to execute a system command using `Runtime exec`. The command requires another JAR file to be able to work but whenever the part where the command will be executed, I am getting an "Error: Unable to access jarfile".

Firstly, my current working directory:

```
assets/jarFile.jar
myApp.jar
```

Here's what my code looks like:

```
try {
  // To get the path of the directory where my current running JAR is
  String jarPath = myApp.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath();
  String path = URLDecoder.decode(jarPath.substring(0, jarPath.lastIndexOf("/")), "UTF-8");

  // The system command to execute
  String command = "java -Xmx1024m -jar "+path+"/assets/jarFile.jar and-so-on...";

  Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
  ...
}
```

The `jarFile.jar` is not an executable JAR by the way.

Any idea?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error: Unable To Access Jar File](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11943948/error-unable-to-access-jar-file)

Comment: @NickL I've also read that question and its answers before I've posted mine. We're in a different case. Not a possible duplicate.

Comment: Oke, so what have you tried? Different location? Wrong slashes in path? Strange symbols? Spaces? Have you tried enclosing it in quotes? Manually entering the full path in exec? Checked the permissions?

Comment: @NickL Yeah I tried a direct path `String command = "java -Xmx1024m -jar D:/assets/jarFile.jar and-so-on...";` still the same...

Comment: Same happens when you run that from terminal?

Comment: First get it to work from commandline. Have you tried different slashes? Backwards instead of forwards? Is the Jar file actually where you expect it to be?

Comment: Yes I test it first from the command line and it's absolutely working. I've also moved the `jarFile.jar` in a different folder in my desktop but still the same error occurs.

Comment: @NickL I've also renamed it and excluded the `.jar`extension as suggested [here](https://bukkit.org/threads/unable-to-access-jar-file.222494/#post-2194718) but still the same...

Comment: So you are saying that the EXACT same command that works on command line, with a full file path for the jar, does not work with runtime.exec? With that I really mean a main class with one line of code which is runtime.exec("java ....."), nothing else. And coincidentally you had the exact same error in another question 9 hours ago? Are you not leaving anything out here?

Comment: Yeah, dunno why it is happening. But nvm, now I got it working with full paths (good news). Seems like the problem is the the code to get the `jarPath` is returning a path which the system can't find. I'll work on it. I appreciate your time and help. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your code to find the path of the jar file does not return the correct path.