# No JAR Files Opening Correctly

Tags: java, jar, executable-jar

I'm trying to open a JAR file, but it won't open. I've tried:

- Reinstalling Java.
- After renaming the file to example.jar, I tried `java -jar` (I got an `Error: Unable to access jarfile example.jar`).
- Double clicking on the file/. I think that it's using JavaTM Platform SE Binary because it shows a little coffee thing as the thumbnail.
- Right clicking and selecting "open with," then selecting JavaTM Platform SE Binary.

What else can I do? I've tried different JAR files as well, and it doesn't work. I guess that there's something wrong with how my system opens the JAR files, but I'm not sure what to do.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: What operating system?

Comment: Have you set the CLASSPATH? It seems that java can't find the jar file you specified

Comment: did you try java -jar example.jar.   Error "Unable to access jarfile" is shown when java could not find the jar file in the current directory

Comment: Have you tried unzip it? Any zip tool will work. The jar format is the same

Comment: Possibly this problem? [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11943948/error-unable-to-access-jar-file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11943948/error-unable-to-access-jar-file)

Comment: @stephenC I'm on Windows 10.

Comment: Oh and does your jar have GUI? If not, nothing will happen if you double click it

Comment: @HilaryLau I haven't done that, but I can look into that.

Comment: @efekctive I'll try that, but the jar file installs something, so I'd prefer to just run it.

Comment: a copy of the file in another dir. this way you will know if it is corrupted

Comment: Oh and you need to use the `cd` command to change to the directory that contains the jar. Else java can't find the jarfile of course

Comment: Thanks everyone for your suggestions; I read over this (per suggestion from @HilaryLau): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11943948/error-unable-to-‌​access-jar-file. I used the complete path to the file in CMD and it worked! I'd like to not have to do that every time, so I'll look into everyone's suggestions more. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for your suggestions; I read over this: [Error: Unable To Access Jar File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11943948/error-unable-to-)‌​access-jar-file. I used the complete path to the file in CMD and it worked! I'd like to not have to do that every time, so I'll look into everyone's suggestions more. Thanks!

Comment: You must either specify the full path or change to the directory that contains it, as I specified earlier. I don't think there is any way around this

Comment: @HilaryLau No 'workaround' required. (a) It is working as documented; (b) it is working exactly the same way as any other command where you specify a filename argument. You have to supply a correct path.