# how to run controlsfx library demo

Tags: java, javafx, controlsfx

Hello could someone please explain to me how to run the controlsfx demo provided in their download folder.  I tried to run it through java in the command line But encountered an error when trying to run the demo. This is the error. .." Error : unable to access jarfile controlsfx-8.20.9.jar " . Any help would be deeply appreciated. 
Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error: Unable To Access Jar File](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11943948/error-unable-to-access-jar-file)

Answer (score 0):

The controlsfx-8.20.9.jar file is a library you are missing. Include that file inside a folder called lib in the same directory where the main executable jar file resides and run again.