# Unable to execute jar from powershell

Tags: powershell, jar

I am trying to execute a jar by using **`java -jar test.jar`**. However, when I keep the jar name in a variable e.g

`$a = "test.jar"`

And try the execution using `java -jar $a`, it gives me an error

```
ERROR: Unable to access jarfile test.jar
```

Answer (score -2):

Error meassage is quite clear, java cannot access the file: check whether you're launching this command in correct directory (where the .jar is located) and your powershell process has permissions to access it.

Comment: I have mentioned that when i execute a jar successfully by giving the jar name. It only fails when the jar name is stores in a variable and then executed. It is pretty evident that location is not the reason for the failure.

Comment: Looks like this is fairly common problem, not only when launching .jar from PS: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11943948/what-causes-unable-to-access-jar-file-error)