# Unable to run my .jar file using .sh file

Tags: java, linux, shell

I have a runnable .jar file, which i can run from my linux terminal but I need to run that .jar file using a .sh file.

```
#!/bin/bash
java -jar executer.jar
```

If i double click the .sh file, terminal opens up but my code doesn't get executed. Kindly let me know, whats wrong.

Comment: If you run this script from terminal everything works?

Comment: may be try this https://askubuntu.com/questions/138908/how-to-execute-a-script-just-by-double-clicking-like-exe-files-in-windows

Comment: More specifically, can you run the java line in a bash terminal?

Comment: If i try to run the .sh file from terminal am getting the following error "Unable to access jarfile/executer.jar"

Comment: @RoyShahaf Yes, using terminal i can run the java line alone. it's working fine. But if i try to run the script, above error is displayed.

Comment: Is the script in the same folder as the jar?

Comment: At any rate this looks similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11943948/what-causes-unable-to-access-jar-file-error . Try moving both script and the jar into a different folder (or using chmod to alter the permissions)

Answer (score 1):

Try moving into sh file location using terminal and try to execute it using following command.

```
 ./startup.sh
```

If your file name is 'startup'

Answer (score 0):

Try to execute a command to output a log file.

Then check the log info.

`java -jar executer.jar >err.log 2>1`

Answer (score 0):

As the question is about "double clicking", try passing the complete path to `java` and give executable permissions (sudo chmod +x <shfile.sh>)

I got a situation like yours and logging the error to a log file, like Henry He's answer, told me that java wasn't found. Even though I can run from the terminal, I got a `java: command not found`

As my java bin comes from `adsf` (*The Multiple Runtime Version Manager*) I passed the complete path and it worked:

```
#!/bin/bash
<complete-path-to-java> -jar executer.jar
```