# I am getting error while running java command on command prompt

Tags: java

I am new to Java.
I am trying to convert mainframe code to Java.
I ran below command line.

`java –jar RES.jar COBOL\C:\Users\Ranjith\Desktop\F9342OLN`

it has given below error

`Error: Unable to access jarfile RES.jar`

May I know how to setup RES.jar.

command line code

```
java –jar RES.jar COBOL\C:\Users\Ranjith\Desktop\F9342OLN

Error: Unable to access jarfile RES.jar
```

Comment: It depends how the app was packaged. The `-jar` option expects the path to the jar file, perhaps `C:\Users\Ranjith\Desktop\F9342OLN\RES.jar`.

Answer (score -1):

This error is caused by being unable to access the jar file.

Possible solutions or hints as to possible problems can be found at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11943948/what-causes-unable-to-access-jar-file-error)