# Unable to access jarfile for my minecraft server

Tags: java, server, minecraft-forge

Hello I need help with my modded minecraft server [Modpack](https://www.curseforge.com/minecraft/modpacks/roguelike-adventures-and-dungeons/files/3255467)
the problem i get
is `unable to access jarfile server.jar`

```
@echo off
java -jar server.jar -Xmx8192M nogui 
pause
```

This is my .bat file where i need to run the server with but it gives the error
Unable to access jarfile server.jar
(the server.jar file is my server)

[My Folder screenshot](https://gyazo.com/162c40c984061377e1370cf2c090b892)

Comment: Please edit your question and include the full text of the error message (preferred as text, not as screen-shot).

Comment: hello robert i have edited the post with the exact error message

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What causes "Unable to access jarfile" error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11943948/what-causes-unable-to-access-jarfile-error)

Answer (score 0):

Is the jar file in the same directory as the bat file? Also, is the name of the file that same as the one you mentioned in your script? The best course of action would be to re-write the bat

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Comment: The names are the same and they are in the same directory,i have rewrote the bat file multiple times but it still doesnt work