# MySQL Compatibility with MacOS Sierra

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, macos-sierra, macos-high-sierra

Does anybody know of any compatibility issues or quirks with MySQL Community Server/Workbench on macOS Sierra?  I recently did an installation on a Mac that had never held MySQL before and it doesn't seem to be working correctly.  (Now maybe I just set it up wrong, but the since the installer offers no advanced options that doesn't seem to be the case.)

I can create schemas and tables, but when I go to actually query the table nothing happens.  The activity indicator spins endlessly.  I took a look at Activity Monitor and it doesn't show `mysqld` actually doing anything—the whole setup just appears to be deadlocked.  Any ideas?

Here's what I'm trying to use:

- MySQL Community Server 5.7.15
- MySQL Workbench 6.3.7
- macOS Sierra 10.12 (16A323)

Comment: Workbench v6.3.8 is out, didn't fix it for me personally, but worth a shot for you guys.

Comment: Workbench v6.3.8 didn't fix it for me either.

Comment: This is the problem... http://www.bonkersworld.net/images/2011.06.27_organizational_charts.png

Almost 3 months since release and it's still not fixed!

Comment: @Philio Yikes!  Any idea how close that is to the truth?

Comment: There is this on the MySQL forum: "this is a known problem. We will provide a fix for it in the next release." http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?152,652686,652950#msg-652950

Comment: Other thread on SO has much better info/solutions relating to this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39399563/mysql-workbench-6-3-mac-hangs-on-simple-queries

Comment: I used to have this and anothers crashing problems often with MySQL Workbench. I had them too on Ubuntu. I finally got tire of it and now I'm using Sequel Pro. It's very basic in comparison to Workbench, but for now, it's OK for me. Just take a look of how many reports about this they have: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=82778

Comment: MySQL Workbench 6.3.9 solves it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I figured it out!  It could have something to do with the *length of the password.*  At first I had just set it up with a single-character password for my convenience, but I ran into some issues when trying to connect the Eclipse BIRT reporting software with MySQL.  I changed the password to make it longer, and that solved the problem with BIRT, but even better, it seems to have solved the problem with Workbench as well!

Answer (score 23):

I had this same issue. I found out that the first instance you open just continues to spin when trying to run simple select statements with what seems to be no reason. You cannot even close the tab once it is open without closing all of MySQL Workbench. However, if you open up the same instance again it seems to work fine.

Comment: You saved my life.

Comment: This works, somewhat. It worked until workbench asked for my db password again, and then subsequently crashed.

Comment: Using a second tab also works for me. So, I started MySQL Workbench and selected my server from the `MySQL Connections` page. Once that opens, don't try to run any queries! Then I went to the menu `Database -> Connect to Database` and opened a new connection to the same server. In the new connection tab, I can run queries without hanging. Unfortunately, it still hangs when trying to quit, so I use `killall MySQLWorkbench` from the command line to quit. Hacky, but it works until they fix this obvious bug...

Answer (score 13):

> ### **UPDATE!**
>
> ### macOS High Sierra ***needs*** MySQL Workbench [6.3.10](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/)
>
> See [*changelog*](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/workbench/en/wb-news-6-3-10.html) for 6.3.10 version

---

### **SOLVED in version 6.3.9**

Tested on:

> macOS Sierra
>   Version 10.12.3 (16D32)

MySQL

> Workbench 6.3.9
>   Version 6.3.9 build 10690321 CE (64 bits) Community
>   `----> OK`

Download: [MySQL Workbench 6.3.9](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/)
<sup>Packages for Sierra (10.12) are compatible with El Capitan (10.11) and are Yosemite (10.10)</sup>

> [Changelog](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/workbench/en/wb-news-6-3-9.html): <sup>*among others...*</sup>
>
> - In some cases, executing a query caused MySQL Workbench to become unresponsive when the host was macOS Sierra. (Bug #25036263, Bug #83658)

---

Original answer in code snippet below:

```html
I ***temporary*** solved changed the ***group*** of the application.  

I tried everything, uninstalling, reinstall, change many settings... finally I thought that must be something with the security... was not normal, I check firewall rules, nothing... And just in case, I try with file permission and it was there.

I was installed in the ***admin group***.  
Changed to ***staff*** solve the problem.  

    $ sudo chown <USER>:staff /Applications/MySQLWorkbench.app

> <sup>Where of course, `<USER>` is **your** username</sup>

    Ex.
    $ sudo chown gmo:staff /Applications/MySQLWorkbench.app

Tested and working!

 - Go back to admin group... problem came back.
 - Changed to staff again... problem solved.

I hope this is a global solution, please check yours.


###Edit:
Solution not stable, problem came back after a few attempts.  
Try with `root:admin`, the same... 

---

### UPDATE
*`Workaround until new version is release`*

Roll back to 6.2 version and working good.

Tested on:
> macOS Sierra  
> Version 10.12 (16A323)

MySQL
> Workbench 6.3  
> Version 6.3.7 build 1199 CE (64 bits) Community  
> http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/6.3.html  
> `----> FAILS`  
> <sup>*Randomly, even changing group or creating new instances.*</sup>

> Workbench 6.2  
> Version 6.2.5.0 build 397 (32 bits) Community  
> http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/6.2.html  
> `----> OK`  
> <sup>*Work as expected.*</sup>
```

Comment: This does nothing for me. If it wasn't for Alex above, I'd advice towards deleting this answer.

Comment: Roll back to 6.2 solve the issue for now... A least as a workaround until new version is release.

Comment: @gmo Rolling back to 6.2.5.0 did not help. Still get the infinite spinner.

Comment: v6.3.8 is released if anyone want to try... [MySQL Workbench 6.3.8 (2016-10-21, General Availability)](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/6.3.html) - [changelog](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/workbench/en/wb-news-6-3-8.html)

Comment: At least for me, v6.3.8 still fails and 6.2.5 still working good.

Comment: sudo chown -R <USER>:staff /Applications/MySQLWorkbench.app worked fro me

Comment: @Rohith, In which version of `workbench` have you applied the modification?

Comment: It's not a perfect solution but workbench is working better than before. workbench 6.3.8. OS 10.12.2.

Comment: v6.3.9 is out and solve the problem! finally... (I will update the answer to share the links and related info)

Comment: 6.3.9 does not resolve problem. Frequently hangs on macOS Sierra and crashes.

Comment: UPDATE: macOS High Sierra ***needs*** MySQL Workbench 6.3.10

Answer (score 4):

In my case MySQL Workbench Community (GPL) for Mac OS X version 6.3.8 CE build 1228 (64 bit) with

```
sudo chown -R <USER>:staff /Applications/MySQLWorkbench.app
```

applied, fixed the problem.

Answer (score 4):

It worked for me when I downgraded the version to 6.1.7 :)

[image]

But missing the quick action icons functionality in the old version :(

Comment: I didn't realize how much I used the quick action icons, but totally works!

Answer (score 2):

MySQL Workbench 6.3.9 is available now (2/14/17) and appears to fix this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, but it was fixed after a reboot. Maybe worth trying.

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem and I digged all internet but dont resolved problem and then I decided use another workbench. I found "DBeaver - Universal Database Manager" official site : http://dbeaver.jkiss.org/ and free and its tolerable.

Answer (score 1):

I got same problem on "macOS 10.12.3" installed "MySQL Workbench Community (GPL) for Mac OS X version 6.3.8 CE build 1228 (64 bit)". It's always not responding after working around I found that problem comes from MSQL Workbench is set "Default Target MySQL Version" wrong version.

***Step 1: open Terminal and check your MYSQL Server version***

```
mysql --version
```

My machine:

> mysql  *Ver 14.14 Distrib **5.7.9**, for osx10.9 (x86_64) using  EditLine
>   wrapper*

***Step 2: Open MySQL Workbench tool then go to "MYSQLWorkbench" near Apple icon on menu***

***Step 3: Workbench Preferences -> Modeling -> MySQL -> Default Target MySQL Version: 5.6***

***Step 4: Change current default from 5.6 into 5.7.9 then OK
Step 5: MYSQLWorkbench -> Quit -> Open and check result.***

Hope this help someone.

Answer (score 0):

Try to reopen the same mysql instance if the Jonathan's solution doesn't resolve your problem, this works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I upgraded mine from 6.2.12 to 6.3.7 and that did the trick for me.

I will note that opening a 2nd tab for the same instance did work, but I found that I could never close the first and it always hung on any query.  And... trying even quit out of the app would require me to force-kill it.  Not an acceptable flow in my opinion, so the upgrade was important to me.  My guess is that the install correctly set permissions or user groups.

Comment: Sierra (10.12)...  but I was using an older MySQL Workbench version prior.

Answer (score 0):

This problem seems to be happening only when using MySQL Workbench.
If you use the command line client (/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql), it is possible to get an answer from mysql server.

Try to do it:
1. Execute /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql --user=YOUR_USER --password=YOUR_PASSWORD
2. Type "use sys;"
3. Type "select * from sys_config;"

Now, we have to find out why the Workbench doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

try using 127.0.0.1 as the hostname, instead of localhost.

Answer (score 0):

On my Mac, sometimes I get the infinite spinner when I try to run queries or close several tabs.

What worked for me was deleting the auto saved workspaces. Delete all entries in 
`~/Library/Application\ Support/MySQL/Workbench/sql_workspaces` 
 or the ones that you know are causing a problem. It works fine after deleting these.

Answer (score 0):

Ver 8.0.23 seems to work ok for me on MacOS 10.12.6 without workbench. I like SequelPro.

Answer (score 0):

mysql workbench version 6.3.10 worked for sierra 10.12.6.
Generally, backward compatibility exists i.e., newer hardware
can operate reasonably older version of software