# unable to close MySql Workbench

Tags: mysql-workbench

Hi I'm using mysql workbench 6.3.8 on Mac OS 10.12

I have a bug. I'm not able to close the workbench properly by using the menu quit or command q.

Could I have miss something during the installation?

Comment: This [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39982373/mysql-compatibility-with-macos-sierra) could be helpful!

Comment: Thanks, I have tried both (changed group and down grade).

Comment: I will try to use mysql command line only. Thanks

Comment: Sorry for the late response. Now I use mysql workbench version 6.2.5  revision 0 build 397 (32 bit) and it works fine. (I have worked also around password)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for the late response. Now I use mysql workbench version 6.2.5 revision 0 build 397 (32 bit) and it works fine. (I have worked also around password) – Patrick Lec 5 mins ago