# mysql workbench 6.3.7 frequently crashes on mac osx El capitan

Tags: mysql-workbench, osx-elcapitan

Its too much irritating to me to use MySQL Workbench 6.3.7 on Mac OSx El Capitan. It firstly **freezes** & then finally **crashes**.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is actually a bug report, not a question.

Comment: This problem has already been reported several times and a solution is comming up in the next release.

Comment: @mike thanks for your reply

Comment: I am running `6.3.8` and it still freezes. As soon as I switched to `Standard (TCP/IP)` from `Standard TCP/IP over SSH` freezing stopped.

Comment: Check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39399563/mysql-workbench-6-3-mac-hangs-on-simple-queries/41725321#41725321) regarding the freezing application.