# results grid not showing on mysql workbench 6.3.9 for macOS sierra

Tags: mysql, macos, workbench

At firs it was working alright, but out of the blue it disappeared, and there is no way to bring it back. Note the gray area with the Apply and Revert buttons, where the results grid should be.

[image: Query just executed, not the all gray area where the results grid should be]

I also tried clicking on the EXPLAIN command icon, then it opens up the Explain pane, and the results grid is there (grayed out). If I click on it, it disappears.

[image]
This is driving me nuts.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: I am not able to see results grid in Mac OS High Sierra...

Comment: Same thing for me since High Sierra, i really shouldnt updated. So many Bugs. I updated everything, mysql, workbench. Nothing helped

Answer (score 55):

Good News!

Apparently this is a widespread bug on macOS High Sierra that was fixed in version 6.3.10 that was released Nov. 15th 2017.

They fixed it as described in the release notes: 
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/workbench/en/wb-news-6-3-10.html

> Executing a query in MySQL Workbench on a host running macOS High
>   Sierra failed to load the result grid completely, which prevented
>   result data from appearing within the Result Grid tab. (Bug #26826418,
>   Bug #87714)

Download it here:
https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/
(No need to uninstall the previous version, just overwrite it with the newer one)

Comment: Thanks man, i was struggling what happened to the output screen? why it is not coming? and then today i found your solution

Comment: Also available using Homebrew: `brew cask install mysqlworkbench`

Comment: Just an FYI, it's still an issue but is intermittent in 8.0.12 (MySQL WB). I have to restart MWB everytime this happens.

Comment: I've got it with MySQLWorkbench version 8.0 on Mojave.

Comment: I got it OS Monterey 12.6.  Updated Workbench and now have to update OS... ughhhh... Now lets update EVERYTHING.... lol (face-palm)

Answer (score 8):

Go there;
[MySQL Workbench 6.3 (Mac) hangs on simple queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39399563/mysql-workbench-6-3-mac-hangs-on-simple-queries)

Still an issue for me on 6.3.9. But I'm running High Sierra (10.13 beta 9) so it might explain why .. Still, I'll probably have to install bootcamp partition.

Comment: I'm on High Sierra Beta 9 as well. But it was happening on Sierra 10.2.6 before installing the Beta, so I don't think is the OS.

Comment: On High Sierra (10.13 (17A365)) there are plenty of new bugs, hanging queries, not showing results panel, not opening more than one connection.... impossible to use. Already did all suggestions found on Google and nothing

Comment: I've just upgrade to 6.3.10 and now it works perfectly.

Answer (score 7):

This was happening on my instance in Ubuntu as well.  Last week, there were no issues and this week, the problem arose.

Reading above, I went to ***Query->Explain Current Statement*** (***CTRL+ALT+x*** in Ubuntu) and saw an empty explain panel with the option to view the Results Grid.  I clicked on the Results Grid and MySQL Workbench crashed.  I re-opened it and ran the query again and the results displayed.  ymmv.

This is definitely a bug.

Comment: I had no crash but this finally got me to display the results grid! Nice one.

Answer (score 5):

It happened with my MySQLWorkbench 8.0 in MacOS High Sierra. I just quit/close MySQL workbench and reopen it again. No need to uninstall and reinstall.

Answer (score 4):

Same for me, since I installed High Sierra the other day it hasn't been working. If I try to run a query twice it'll freeze up. I also tried to uninstall the workbench and install an older version but it had the same problem.

EDIT: Version 6.1.7 works better. It still has some issues with large result sets but much easier to do some simple development with.

Answer (score 4):

I had this problem too. Since updating to High Sierra it stopped working.

However, finally, there is a working version out there.
https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=87714

EDIT:
You have to remove your current Workbench version, download and install the .dmg provided in the link above and it should work.
At least it worked for me - and as seen within the comments of the link -, for a lot of other people.

Comment: Please include the answer directly in your SO post. Links may be useful but they do not constitute a proper answer.

Comment: Did anyone else's Mac prompt for every password in the keychain again when the .dmg file included in the above link was installed? I got prompted for github, email, database instances, icloud password.

Is this file to be trusted?

Comment: Hey, I haven't had this issue.
However, this seems weird.

Answer (score 1):

On macOS Sierra, the 6.1.7 version works without issues. The newer versions are very buggy

Answer (score 1):

The latest version of MySQL Workbench (6.3.10) fixed that issue for me. But it still has few "stopped unexpectedly" kinda issues.

Comment: Same for me. I had the issue with 6.3.9 on High Sierra 10.13.6 but updating to 6.3.10 fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I wish i had not done the Mac update but I just uninstalled My SQL Workbench and reinstalled it with no issues. I now can run my queries and see the results grid.