# Error while using a created function with mysql workbench

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have a problem with calling a function I created using MySQL Workbench. 
Function:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION welcome()
RETURNS TEXT
deterministic
BEGIN
    RETURN 'Hello World!';
END
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

After I hit this button:
[buttonMySQL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U0Xn8.png)

[image]

I get:
"Error parsing sql code for object
Syntax error: unexpected 'COLLATE' (collate)"

Funny thing is when i call this function using code, like:

```
SELECT world.welcome();
```

It works.

Comment: I thought this was a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39399563/mysql-workbench-6-3-mac-hangs-on-simple-queries but that problem is that queries hang, instead of getting a syntax error like you report. So I have reversed my vote to mark your question a duplicate.

Comment: I tried your function with MySQL 8.0.1 and MySQL Workbench 6.3.2.0 and it works fine with no error.

Comment: It sounds a bit like Workbench strikes yet again, parsing code it doesn't need to be parsing, trying to reverse engineer the function instead of just running it.

Comment: Just tested that on macOS with WB 6.3.9 and it works as intended. Clicking on the flash icon opens a new SQL editor with the text `selelct test.welcome()` and runs it. This opens a result set with a single column and row, containing the "Hello World" text. What MySQL server and WB version do you use? What does the WB log show?

Comment: I'm using mysql server 5.7.22 on Ubuntu 16.04.5 with Workbench 6.3.10 and I get the same error when I execute the same script above. I don't think that question is duplicate.