# Mac OSX file permissions has '@' - how to remove that '@'

Tags: linux, macos, file-permissions, chmod, darwin

How can I remove that '@' character from the file permissions?

'**@**' in file permissions for Mac/OSX machines, is used to show that an extended attribute is set with this file.

1. Tried `chmod 755 galaxy-ansible.yml` but that didn't help.
2. Tried    `echo | chmod -E galaxy-ansible.yml`, didn't help (even with using `sudo`).
3. Tried `xattr -d  galaxy-ansible.yml`, that didn't help either (even with using `sudo`).

I even did the above operations as **root** user, still '@' character is not going away from file's permissions.

```
[arun@MacBook-Pro-2 ~/aks/anisble] $ ls -l@ galaxy-ansible.yml 
-rwxr-xr-x@ 1 arun  staff  270 Dec 22 12:31 galaxy-ansible.yml
    com.apple.quarantine     67
```

My ~/aks folder is mapped to a CentOS vagrant box and if I'm on the vagrant box, doing `ls -l` doesn't give me '@' (as it's not a Max/OSX machine):

```
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 vagrant vagrant  270 Dec 22 00:12 galaxy-ansible.yml
```

On my Mac/OSX machine, there are other .yml files but those don't have '@' in the file permissions so I'm trying to remove '@' from galaxy-ansible.yml file (on Mac machine).

Right now the whole roles/.. folder has '@' character for any folder/files.

```
-rwxr-xr-x@ 1 arun  staff  1132 Dec 21 17:12 README.md
drwxr-xr-x@ 3 arun  staff   102 Dec 21 17:12 defaults
drwxr-xr-x@ 3 arun  staff   102 Dec 21 17:12 handlers
drwxr-xr-x@ 4 arun  staff   136 Dec 21 17:12 meta
drwxr-xr-x@ 5 arun  staff   170 Dec 21 17:12 tasks
drwxr-xr-x@ 7 arun  staff   238 Dec 21 17:12 templates
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I remove the "extended attributes" on a file in Mac OS X?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4833052/how-do-i-remove-the-extended-attributes-on-a-file-in-mac-os-x)

Comment: @FrankSchmitt Thanks Frank. Using `xattr -c file` or `xattr -cr folder` fixed it. I didn't look good enough.

Comment: The way this question is phrased is helpful for a searcher that isn't familiar with the 'extended attributes' terminology (which is probably most people). So although it's a duplicate I found myself googling almost the identical question as phrased here and probably wouldn't have found the other question.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The following commands helped in clearing the extended attribute at file / folder(recursive) level.

```
xattr -c <yourfilename>
```

or

```
xattr -cr <yourfoldername>
```

Comment: This didn't remove the '@' character in the file permissions of a .net maui project on mac for me