# pre-commit hook not working in macOS but working in Ubuntu

Tags: bash, git, macos, githooks

I have a git pre-commit hook script to validate certain thing during commit.

This in my script `.githooks/pre-commit`

```sh
#!/bin/bash

echo "Here I am!"
```

This is the file permission
[image: file permission]

In ubantu when I am committing anything I am able to view the echoed message, where as when I doing the the same thing in MacOS I am getting this error

> **fatal: cannot run .githooks/pre-commit: No such file or directory**

git config is `.git/config`

[image: git config]

line break type is CRLF
[image: crlf]

Also when I am directly running the file (*in MacOS*) from CLI like this, it is giving me the desired output.

```sh
./.githooks/pre-commit
```

My git version is `2.32.0 (Apple Git-132)`

Comment: the directory is `.git/hooks` **not** `.githooks`

Comment: @AnthonySottile `core.hooksPath` is set.

Comment: What version of Git are you using on MacOS? `core.hookspath` was new in Git 2.9.0. Apple should be distributing a later version now but perhaps you have a very old Mac.

Comment: @torek: my git version is `2.32.0 (Apple Git-132)`.

Comment: OK... seems like it should work then, especially if `./.githooks/pre-commit` works. (However, you should be using LF-only lines on macOS.)

Comment: Please [don’t post images of code, error messages, or other textual data.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Answer (score 0):

could you please try this and see if it's working for you?

```
brew link --overwrite git
brew update git
```

You should have the latest version of git -> 2.35.x

Now go to your local repository, i.e. the project folder, and then to the **.git/hooks** directory under your project folder.

You can place your hook files here. I.e. for pre-commit, the file name should be **pre-commit** (without any extension).

This should work whenever you try to commit to that specific repository. The main problem in your case seems to be the directory. The hooks should be in the **.git/hooks** directory of the project folder.

See the screenshots below.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Replacing all of Git in the hope that this will fix what seems like a permission problem seems like overkill. Do you have a reason to believe this will answer the OP's actual question?

Answer (score 0):

Because of macos security restriction, called extended attribute(xattr).[mac-osx-file-permissions-has-how-to-remove-that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41290761/mac-osx-file-permissions-has-how-to-remove-that)

```bash
xattr -d com.apple.provenance pre-commit
```