# How to remove @ (extended attributes) from files on MacOS?

Tags: macos

I find that .h with extended attributes files will cause Xcode crashed.

I tried to remove extended attributes like this link [How do I remove the "extended attributes" on a file in Mac OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4833052/how-do-i-remove-the-extended-attributes-on-a-file-in-mac-os-x) 
But nothing helps.

Even that `xattr xattr Moya-umbrella.h` outputs nothing.
`xattr -c Moya-umbrella.h` changes nothing.
`xattr -rd com.apple.quarantine Moya/` changes nothing.

I tried that `cat Moya-umbrella.h > Moya-umbrella.dat` get a file without extended attributes (@).

But when I `cat Moya-umbrella.dat > Moya-umbrella3.h` will get a file with extended attributes(@).

I researched that `ditto` can copy file without extended attributes.

`ditto --norsrc --noextattr --noqtn --nocache --nopreserveHFSCompression Alamofire-umbrella.dat Alamofire-umbrella3.h` but It failed again.

I have tried any methods that I researched but all not work.

My MacOS is 10.13.6 (High Sierra)

I am developing iOS projects but Xcode will crash when copying files with extended attributes(@) like ".h".

I have struggled with this for more time but nothing helps.

Comment: What does `ls -leO@` on the file show?

Comment: @GordonDavisson Thanks for your comment.
It seems no valuable info shown.
`ANDYLI2:Moya andyli2$ ls -leO@ Moya-umbrella.h
-rw-r--r--@ 1 andyli2  staff  - 300 Dec 20 13:37 Moya-umbrella.h
                                                                                                                          ?  -1`

Comment: It seems nobody else encountered the issue?